# Are there changes in Bootstrap.releaseExternalResources() between Netty 3.5 and Netty 3.6?

Tags: netty

On shutting down my netty application while using netty 3.6 the process does not terminate on calling releaseExternalResources() on my server and/or client bootstraps. (The project uses ClientBootstrap and ServerBootstrap. On testing, the process goes into an infinite loop on the first called bootstrap shutdown)

I can clearly bring it down to netty, because it depends on just changing the version number 3.5 to 3.6 in my project's POM. Has anyone a hint for my on that case?

Best regards
Martin

Edit: Unit-Test of how I create bootstraps and share thread pools which works under Netty 3.5 and doesn't with Netty 3.6

```
@Test
public void testRelease() {

    // create bootstraps
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    final ClientBootstrap client = new ClientBootstrap(
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(pool,
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
    final ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap(
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(pool,
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    // release resources
    System.out.println("Releasing resources - client...");
    client.releaseExternalResources();
    System.out.println("Releasing resources - server...");
    server.releaseExternalResources();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there was some changes.. But calling releaseExternalResources() on the bootstrap should shutdown everything like expected. If that is not the case please open a bug-report

Comment: Thank you. I could write a unit test that reproduces the problem. The issue is open: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1120

Comment: I have noticed, that maybe my way of creating bootstraps is not the best. But currently I am a bit of confused while trying to find the best way. The new approach with BossPool and WorkerPool is badly documented to me.
Although the bug, that Netty 3.5 supported my crooked solution and Netty 3.6 doesn't is still real to me.